# How to start from top after page change when using neon-animated-pages

Tags: polymer

When using neon-animated-pages if the page change event is triggered when you are not at the top of the current page, it will switch to the new page equally as far down the page. The default behavior should be to switch pages and show the top of the new page.

Is there a workaround to scroll to the top of the page after the new page is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around it by setting the scrollTop to the element that contained the neon-animated-pages.I do this from the function that is called when I press on the button that changes my neon-animated-page.

```
document.querySelector('my-container').scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: that will work but can cause janky animations. cause the page is trying to scroll to the top and animate pretty much @ the same time.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience it is best for each page to have their own paper-header-panel, toolbar and ect. then when you change pages the next page will be @ the top and the page you are leaving will have a memory of the scroll location when you left the page. This way seemed to have a better user experience for me.

```
<neon-animated-pages selected="{{page}}">
  <neon-animatable>
    <paper-header-panel>
      <paper-toolbar></paper-toolbar>
      //page 1
    </paper-header-panel>
  </neon-animatable>
  <neon-animatable>
    <paper-header-panel>
      <paper-toolbar></paper-toolbar>
      // page 2
    </paper-header-panel>
  </neon-animatable>
</neon-animated-pages>
```

only other real option is to use the event fired when neon animation ends.

```
<paper-header-panel id="panel">

Polymer({
  is: 'custom-element',
  listeners: {
    'neon-animation-finish': '_onNeonAnimationFinish'
  },
  _onNeonAnimationFinish: function(e) {
    document.querySelector('#panel').scroller().scrollTop = 0;
    // or if panel is in same element 
    this.$.panel.scroller().scrollTop = 0;
  }
});
```

this method combined with other functions ran after the animation cause my apps animations to look kind of janky.. this may not always be the case just my  experience.

Answer (score 0):

This is solvable in CSS. What you need to do is to create an individual scrolling context within each page. To do so, set the following:

HTML:

```
<paper-header-panel>
  <paper-toolbar></paper-toolbar>

  <neon-animated-pages selected="{{page}}">
  <neon-animatable>
    <div class="wrapper>
      // Page 1
    </div>
  </neon-animatable>
  <neon-animatable>
    <div class="wrapper>
      // Page 2
     </div>
   </neon-animatable>
</neon-animated-pages>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* Not always required depending on the stacking context of your site */
}
neon-animatable {
  height: 100%;
}
neon-animated-pages {
  height: 100%;
}
```

The great thing about this solution is that each page remembers it's previous scrolling position – so if you scroll down in page 1, jump to page 2, scroll around in page 2 and jump back to page 1, you'll return where you left in page 1.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the change event listener:

```
$('#mainContainer').scrollTop(0);
```

For instance:

```
$('paper-tabs paper-tab').click(function(){
  $('#mainContainer').scrollTop(0);
  scope.selected = $('paper-tabs paper-tab').index(this)
});
```

Your neon animated / iron pages are likely within a paper-header-panel  (common if using the Polymer Starter Kit).

See https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/issues/285